# Win 7, Android, iOS SDK

Tags: android, ios, windows-7, sdk

I am currently working on an application that will be run on Windows 7 Tablet. Suddenly, the customers wanted the same application to be runnable on Windows 7, Android and even iOS. I have looked into Adobe Flex and it is capable of building Android and iOS application with the same code.

I was wondering is there any SDK out there which could do the same thing as Flex as to build Win 7, Android and iOS app at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phone gap](http://www.phonegap.com/about/features) provides decent support for Android and iOS. Not sure about Windows 7. Before you start off [cross platform mobile](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CrossPlatformMobile.html) article by Martin Fowler is worth reading.